# How to download audio file from blob URL in Angular 6?

Tags: typescript, audio, blob, html5-audio, angular6

I am trying to produce an audio file (.mp3 format) after recording for 2500 milliseconds. I am using `navigator` and mainly make use of HTML5-audio. I am generating a link for downloading the file.
`window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)` returns `blob:http://localhost:4200/e6a5a51e-ae11-4b77-9b2c-06251b13ca39`. I don't know how to turn this into a file to be able to download.

This is how the function of recording looks like:

```
  this.record = () => {     
      var headers = new Headers();
      var browser = <any>navigator;      
      var obj = {
        audio: true,
        sampleSize: 16
      };

      var audio = document.createElement('audio');      

      browser.getUserMedia = (browser.getUserMedia || browser.webkitGetUserMedia || browser.mozGetUserMedia || browser.msGetUserMedia);
      browser.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(obj).then(stream => {            
        setTimeout(function(){        
          var track = stream.getTracks()[0]; 
          var source = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);   // returns blob:http://localhost:4200/e6a5a51e-ae11-4b77-9b2c-06251b13ca39
          audio.src = source;      
          audio.autoplay= true; 
          var link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = source;
          link.download = 'audio_recording_' + new Date().getTime() + '.mp3'; //"audioSample.wav";
          link.innerHTML = "Click here to download the file";
          document.body.appendChild(link); 

          track.stop(); 
          // window.URL.revokeObjectURL(stream);    
        }, 2500);

      });
    };
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It appears that you've done it already.  Just don't assume that the file is going to be an MP3.  What's the specific issue you're having?

Answer (score 5):

audio and video are in the same format webm in chrome.

Same like video

1.record audio in 'audio/webm' mimeType

2.download blob in webm format

3.convert webm to mp3(or you can also convert using javascript before download,but it real cost time though it's easy to find solution in github.Maybe it will be sloved by native api)

ref:https://github.com/webrtc/samples

ios reference to wav:https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill and 
https://github.com/kaliatech/web-audio-recording-tests

e.x. in chrome

```
  function startRecording() {
  recordedBlobs = [];
  let options = {mimeType: 'audio/webm'};

  try {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(window.stream, options);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder:', e);
    errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `Exception while creating MediaRecorder: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`;
    return;
  }

  console.log('Created MediaRecorder', mediaRecorder, 'with options', options);
  recordButton.textContent = 'Stop Recording';
  playButton.disabled = true;
  downloadButton.disabled = true;
  mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => {
    console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event);
  };
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.start(10); // collect 10ms of data
  console.log('MediaRecorder started', mediaRecorder);
}

const downloadButton = document.querySelector('button#download');
downloadButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type : 'audio/webm'});
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'test.webm';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the blob is indeed a valid blob and the error is in your code to make the download available: I've had success with [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

Answer (score -1):

try creating a **new Audio** referring to your **source** as it follows below:

```
var audioFile = new Audio(source)
```

and in your **link.href** and **audio.src** try setting it such as:

```
audio.src = audioFile
link.href = audioFile
```

Please let me know if this worked!