# How to Convert WAV file to MP3 in time of download in Angular 8

Tags: angular, audio, audio-recording

My application requirement is that user will record audio in browser and the file will be saved to server and a local copy also can be kept.  I am using Angular 8, I am able to record audio. When i am downloading it by clicking the "download" from the audio control, it is being downloaded in WAV format.  But i need MP3 format, cause WAV file size is big.

I am following this example. [RecordRTCDemo](https://github.com/moneychaudhary/RecordRTCDemo)

I have changed the `mimeType: 'audio/mp3'` but it is not working. So far, i know, RecordRTC use `webm` format to record.

I tried it the code example in different browser. I have also looked at the question : 
[How to download audio file from blob URL in Angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444614/how-to-download-audio-file-from-blob-url-in-angular-6),
but not understanding how to apply the solution of this question.

Comment: Not all browsers have the MP3 codec available.  Also, if your reason is that you don't want the larger WAV file with PCM, then consider actually using WebM which is going to use Opus for audio.  Opus is actually more efficient than MP3, providing significantly better audio quality for a given bitrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ffmpeg.js, this can help you convert your WAV file to a better compressed file format in OGG or mp3

https://github.com/muaz-khan/Ffmpeg.js/blob/master/wav-to-ogg.html